# AWS Ruby SDK for RDS

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

All, I'm trying to determine the replication status of a read replica in RDS via a script. It appears that this info is not exposed as a simple property of the RDS instance, but instead you have to use the lower level Client class. This returns AWS::Core::Response. So:

```
rds = AWS::RDS.new
client = rds.client

result = client.describe_db_instances({:db_instance_identifier => 'db instance id'})
```

This returns:

```
 => {:db_instances=>[{:db_security_groups=>[{:status=>"active", :db_security_group_name=>"blah"}], :vpc_security_groups=>[], :db_parameter_groups=>[{:parameter_apply_status=>"in-sync", :db_parameter_group_name=>"blah"}], :read_replica_db_instance_identifiers=>[], :option_group_memberships=>[{:option_group_name=>"blah", :status=>"in-sync"}], :status_infos=>[{:message=>"errors message here", :status=>"error", :status_type=>"read replication", :normal=>false}], :backup_retention_period=>0, :multi_az=>false, :db_instance_status=>"available", :db_instance_identifier=>"db instance identifier", :preferred_backup_window=>"04:50-05:20", :preferred_maintenance_window=>"fri:06:00-fri:06:30", :availability_zone=>"us-east-1a", :engine=>"mysql", :pending_modified_values=>nil, :license_model=>"general-public-license", :endpoint=>{:port=>3306, :address=>"endpint"}, :engine_version=>"5.5.27", :read_replica_source_db_instance_identifier=>"datamgmt-production", :publicly_accessible=>true, :db_name=>"datamgmt", :auto_minor_version_upgrade=>true, :instance_create_time=>2014-05-06 22:05:27 UTC, :allocated_storage=>40, :db_instance_class=>"instance class", :master_username=>"username"}], :response_metadata=>{:request_id=>"id"}}
```

According to the AWS Ruby SDK at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/frames.html ,

```
my_hash = result.data
```

Will return a hash.

I'm now just trying to get the :status_infos piece of the return.

```
my_hash['status_infos'] #returns nil
my_hash['db_instances']
```

Running the [Awesome Print](https://github.com/michaeldv/awesome_print) gem shows the output of my_hash as a color coded hash, so I'm at a loss why I can't retrieve the data I want to get. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access the [Hash](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html) keys with a `:symbol` not a `'string'`

```
my_hash[:status_infos]
my_hash[:db_instances]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply? How do I get deeper into the nesting? my_hash[:db_instances] returns everything inside that. my_hash[:db_instances][0] returns the first subgroup. 

but my_hash[:db_instances][1], my_hash[:db_instances][0][1] rerurn nil, as does my_hash[:status_infos]

Comment: Some trial and error: my_hash[:db_instances][0][:status_infos][0][:status_type].

Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: You got it. Arrays of Hashes, painful.